# Explicit value type constraints with typescript generics?

Tags: typescript

I have this function:

```
function filterByCourseNumber(data: IPost[] | IExam[], courses: string[]) {
  if (courses.length === 0) return data;
  return data.filter((item) => _includes(courses, item.courseNumber));
}
```

It works fine when I pass in `IPost[]`, but when I do:

```
exams = filterByCourseNumber(exams, filters.courses)
```

I have this error:

```
Type 'IPost[]' is not assignable to type 'IExam[]'.
  Type 'IPost' is not assignable to type 'IExam'.
    Types of property 'claimer' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
let exams: IExam[]
```

I know I need to use generics, but I can't figure out how to write my interface.

I tried:

```
function filterByCourseNumber<T>(data: T[], courses: string[]): T[] {
  if (courses.length === 0) return data;
  return data.filter((item) => _includes(courses, item.courseNumber));
}
```

But `item.courseNumber` has the error:

```
Property 'courseNumber' does not exist on type 'T'.
```

I think I'm close, but I'm not sure how to make my function know that `T` can only be `IPost` or `IExam`.

Comment: It would really be useful if you included all the code in your example.  For instance, both `IPost` and `IExam` are missing so we don't know properties those have even though you're example uses properties on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constrain your type parameter to be of type `IPost | IExam` only.

```
function filterByCourseNumber<T extends IPost | IExam>(data: T[], courses: string[]): T[] {
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that in the docs but I didn't know how to extend a union. Makes perfect sense :-)

Comment: I can't figure out why by now I get https://www.dropbox.com/s/1emsa7nnh69ttym/carbon.png?dl=0

Comment: I wish I could help, but I don't use ESLint, and it seems like an ESLint parsing error. Your code is perfectly valid TypeScript.